# How can I sort list of objects based on a button

Tags: django, sorting, element

I'm a newbie to Django, and I want to add a sort  of a button for sorting elements according to date, descending and ascending order.
The idea is to add a button or carousel in the template page. and based on the click decide the sorting if ascending or descending order.

I cant figure out how to link the button to the backend.

I know that the queryset:

```
post.objects.order_by('date')
```

the button is created as:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label  class="font-weight-light text-warning text-info " for="exampleFormControlSelect1" >Sort by date</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sort">
        <option id="NtF">New to old</option>
        <option id = "FtN">old to new</option>

    </select>
```